# Why VideoPlayerViewController can be presented from iPad but not from iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a universal app and 2 storyboards(for iPad and iPhone). In a view controller, when I tap a button, a video is starting to play. I am doing that with:

```
-(void)playMoviesForItems:(NSArray *)shopItems{
    VideoPlayerViewController* moviePlayer = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"videoPlayerController"];
    [self presentViewController:moviePlayer animated:NO completion:nil];
    [moviePlayer playMoviesForItems:shopItems];
}
```

In iPad, everything works fine. But in iPhone, i can hear the sound of the movie, but there is no view. It is not presented like it does in iPad.

So where am I wrong? Is it the good way to present a video controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your frame for the video player is not setted properly.You have to use proper class or like present modal view controller.I am able to play the video in iphone using video player.How come it will not work for you?Is apple making junk changes i hope not so..